# Faster API calls with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, api

I'm making an app called "Your Life in Music" where the user plugs in his/her birthdate and the app displays the top billboard hit from each birthday since they were born. The app is currently pretty slow since it takes a while to retrieve all the album cover images from the Last.fm api. I'm wondering how one can speed up API calls with JS/jQuery. It seems like threading might solve this but I'm not sure how to implement that...

Here's the app: http://www.dailyspiro.com

And the critical code:

```
function compileDisplay(birthDays) {
    // create an HTML list that for each birthday displays top song, artist, and album art
    htmlObj = {}
    for (i = 0; i < birthDays.length; i++) {
        var age = birthDays[i][0]; // age isn't equal to i if user was born before 1958
        var date = birthDays[i][1];
        try {
            var track = billboard[date]['song'];
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(date)
        }
        var artist = billboard[date]['artist'];
        getAlbumArt(age, track, artist, birthDays);
    }
}

function getAlbumArt(age, track, artist, birthDays) {
    $.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=6ad5bad28ffc4dedbcf1115b3ddf5273&artist=" + artist + "&track=" + track + "&format=json&callback=?", function (data) {
        try {
            var image = data.track.album.image[2]['#text'];
            if (image == 'http://cdn.last.fm/flatness/catalogue/noimage/2/default_album_medium.png') {
                throw 'generic image';
            }
        } catch (err) {
            var image = 'images/' + track + '.jpg';
        }
        compileHtml(age, track, artist, image, birthDays)
    })
}
```

Comment: It depends on the service api .. its not upto you .. cant speed it up with javascript.

Comment: The ajax calls are already async, and it doesn't look like you're blocking anywhere. You could look at the network tab of your browser tools to see how long each request is actually taking.

Comment: The API calls are already parallel (but many, not sure whether you could optimize that). Yet, the felt slowliness of your app seems to come from the carousel script waiting for all images to load (which are taking quite a time)

Comment: One thing you could do is preload the data for all probable birthdays -- maybe once they fill out the month, but not the day, start fetching the JSON for all days for that month? They probably won't like you hitting their server 30 times at once, though.

Comment: It looks like your javascript takes about 140ms, and the ajax calls (for me) take around 1.5s. So the time spent is loading the images before displaying the carousel. You could probably take a second or so off if you could combine all the API calls into one request. You might also try not waiting for all the images to load before displaying the carousel somehow.

Comment: Great ideas, everyone! I changed the carousel so that it doesn't preload all the images before starting to display them. It's definitely faster now, but the api calls still are slow, at least on my computer...

Comment: @JasonP or anyone else, how can I combine the API calls into one request? (I'm a bit of a newbie, so not sure how to do this...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General notes:

1. You are missing lots of ; at the end of some lines
2. The birthDays object's last element has a , after it which is wrong
3. The birthDays object is huge (try to figure out another way to deal with it if you can.
4. Besides the guys' suggestions made above (especially the comment made by @Jason P regarding merging all requests into one), I would recommend the following:

---

Since birthDays is huge, I would recommend creating multiple objects say every 5 or 10 years
this will speed up the looping

---

The drawback is that you have now to loop on multiple objects so maybe you could organize them something like this

{ d60To65:{........}, d65To70:{.......} ..... }

plus this would add to the complexity of your code

---

Note: js objects are unordered as per the specs (which is the case for your inner objects - the birthdays)

for this reason I would suggest you use JS Linked List to secure ordering

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/04/13/computer-science-in-javascript-linked-list/

5- Fix your loop maybe like this `for (var i = 0, l = birthDay.length; i < l; i++)`

6- Put your vars directly after the function start instead of creating them on each loop

```
 var age = 0; //number as it can't be otherwise and now you can easily make checks on it
    var date = ""; //a string for the same reasons as age
    var artist = ""; //same comment
    var track = ""; //same comment
```

same comment on vars in functions (where you might find them)

7- You might want to check [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) if you found yourself using js dates as it has some utility functions for that

Hope this helped

and for some reason the carousel is not working on Firefox 22 (if you need it supported)

Comment: really helpful answer and great tips! As a followup question, how can I combine the API calls into one request? (I'm a bit of a newbie, so not sure how to do this...)

Comment: from the api, I did not see anything offering merging for your case. However, I have noticed that there are other api calls which you might be able to use, specifically http://www.last.fm/api/show/user.getTopTracks, if you can make a list of top tracks on your last.fm account the same as birthDays (and this time ordered by ranking to date on last.fm) and in birthDays match the date to the ranking for example "9-8-1990":"1" (in your case "artist": "Jon Bon Jovi", "song": "Blaze Of Glory" <-- this should be on last.fm one of your top tracks, this way you'll have a match and control ability

Comment: to continue with the idea, order the rankings by date (so my above example is not correct), thus 1 would match  "8-9-1958": {"artist": "Ricky Nelson", "song": "Poor Little Fool"} and so forth, this will make it easier for you to filter them and extract the needed info

Note that in the case you get them all, if you can follow @skatanick advice it would be best, as I don't think the info will change from request to other (so caching on your server is the way to go) and if you can do some server ordering and filtering as needed it will be best for your case

Comment: Lol at the "you need semicolons at the end of your lines". This answer is OLD!

Answer (score 2):

It sure takes a long time... especially for old timers like me!

I'd suggest that you start building the carousel with default images, then replace them with the actual images as and when they get loaded.

Nice idea btw!

Comment: Thanks! That's a good point. I just did something similar...changed carousel so that it doesn't preload all the images before displaying. It's now a bit faster...

Answer (score 1):

If the API let you ( check the user agreement), you can try to cache or to store the API data on your server so you would not have to connect to the API each time you load the apps.